# PHP/SQL Query where tables match (wildcard)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, match

Last time you guys were super helpful, let's hope we can also resolve the following challenge that I'm having.

I have 2 tables in the same database and trying to match fields. Here is the query I'm looking for with the table name however I cannot get it to work:

I want to MATCH table "projects" and Column "categorysecond" table "users_profile" and Column "category".

projects.categorysecond might include example; "Roofing,Windows,Landscaping" and users_profile.category might only have EITHER "Roofing" OR "Windows" OR "Landscaping", so I want to pull the results from "projects" if a result from users_profile.category FITS in projects.categorysecond

***Important - I do not have unique identifiers to do a inner join on example ID. The only match should be on the tables listed above, if words(%Wildcard) from one fits the other.

SAMPLE OF MY ATTEMPT

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT users_profiles.username, projects.id FROM users_profiles, projects  WHERE users_profiles.category like '%' + projects.categorysecond + '%'";
```

Does this make sense? :)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results *in tabular format* in the question.  Second, storing lists of things as a comma-delimited string is a really, really, really, really bad idea.  You should explain why you have chosen such a bad way to represent the category relationship.

Comment: Added sample of my attempt above. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select  distinct 
        up.username
       ,p.id 
from   users_profiles  as up
        join    projects as p
        on      concat(',',p.categorysecond,',') like concat('%,',up.category,',%')
```

Comment: Hello @dudu!

Little issue now that I did more testing. When my field users.profiles(category) has Roofing and my field projects(categorysecond) has Roofing it does pull a results HOWEVER, as soon as I input another categorysecond and store it after Roofing (example Roofing;Painting;) it no longer finds Roofing.

I took the suggestion from Gordon Linoff and reformated all the entries in categorysecond from word1,word2,word3; to word1;word2;word3;

Also, I tried the find_in_set() as Gordon Linoff suggested but get no results.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Current query is:

SELECT distinct p.id, p.categorysecond, p.enteredtime, p.startdate, p.city, p.province FROM users_profiles as up join projects as p ON concat(',',p.categorysecond,',') like concat('%,',up.category,',%') AND p.status LIKE ''

Answer (score 0):

You have a really bad data format.  You should not be storing lists of things in a comma-delimited field.  The trouble you are having with this query is just one example of the issues.  You cannot get such queries to take advantage of indexes or other optimization techniques.

Sometimes, we are stuck with other people's really bad design decisions.  MySQL has the function `find_in_set()` with works in this case:

```
SELECT DISTINCT up.username, p.id
FROM users_profiles up JOIN
     projects p 
     ON find_in_set(up.category, p.categorysecond) > 0;
```

Note:  If you don't need the `DISTINCT`, then don't include it.  It just incurs a performance penalty.

Comment: Hello Gordon, seem I'm still having some challenges. I took some of you feedback but see my reply from above.